# rename url content

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

when url= http://www.iranfairco.com/MainPP.aspx?idCompany=142707090021 .

change content `MainPP.aspx` by `idCompany` 
for example `idCompany=142707090021`  equal companyName `microsoft`

no how can when user enter url: http://www.iranfairco.com/microsoft this equal above url

how can http://www.iranfairco.com/MainPP.aspx?idCompany=142707090021====url:http://www.iranfairco.com/microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some url rewrite module (or write your own - it's not hard).
For example: [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), also look [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/).

Look at also this thourough explanation of how [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) works.